Spaces in file name in MSDOS batch file
This is the error I have when running my test.bat file:
C:\Users>test.bat

C:\Dir1 1\file.csv

The system cannot find the file C:\Dir1.

This is the test.bat file content:
@Echo off

set "source=C:\Dir1 1\filename.csv"

echo %source%

for /F "Delims=" %%g in (%source%) do (@echo %%g)

As you can see the space in directory name seems to be the issue. How do I fix this?

Add quotes (double quotes, not single quotes). Basic Windows practice: anything with spaces in it needs to be (fully) quoted.

There are double quotes there already: set "source=C:\Dir1 1\filename.csv"

put the quotes around just the part to the right of = , that is the file path.

@DaveS that won't work as expected, as that includes the double quotes in the value of source, which is not what OP likely wants - see answer below.

If I add another set of double quotes like : set "source="C:\Dir1 1\test1.csv"" this is what I get: C:\Users>d:\mytest.bat
"C:\Dir1 1\test1.csv"
C:\Dir1 1\test1.csv

You correctly quote the set statement:
set "source=C:\Dir1 1\filename.csv"

This sets source to be C:\Dir1 1\filename.csv, and the double quotes around the entire assignment ensure that the double quotes don't end up in the value of source, but still avoid including trailing spaces, etc. As evidenced by your echo statement:
echo %source%

Consider adding quotes here, to make it perfectly clear there is nothing untoward here.
Your issue is with the for statement:
for /F "Delims=" %%g in (%source%) do (@echo %%g)

This should be either:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`type "%source%"`) do (@echo %%g)

Or:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in ("%source%") do (@echo %%g)

The first one works, because the backticks are now interpreted as containing a command to execute, and the value of %source% is placed in double quotes, to ensure values with spaces are processed correctly by the type command, which just returns ("types") the lines of the file.
The second one works, because the double quotes directly around the value in parentheses indicate to for that this is a file to be processed line by line, and the filename can contain spaces without issues due to the quotes.
So, a corrected version:
@echo off
set "source=C:\Dir1 1\filename.csv"
echo "%source%"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in ("%source%") do (@echo %%g)

A great source for details on these commands is here: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html
